# UPDATE from result of SELECT

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update, greatest-n-per-group

I have a problem with updating my table with a select from another table. Here is my description:

Table `part` has the following fields:

```
part_num PK
active 
notes
weight
```

Table `importedDocument` has the following fields:

```
part_num PK
active
notes
weight
quantity PK
condition_id  PK
```

`part_num` in `part` is unique, but `part_num` in `importedDocument` is not. Every `part_num` that is in `importedDocument` is also in `part`. What I want to do is to get `DISTINCT` `part_num` from `importedDocuemnt`, and with this result I want to update `active`, `notes` and `weight` in part for all the `part_num` that are in `importedDocument`.

So far I have this:

```
UPDATE part
   SET    
   active = importedDocument.active, 
   notes = importedDocument.notes,      
   weight = importedDocument.weight, 
   condition_id = importedDocument.condition_id
FROM  importedDocument
WHERE part.part_num IN (SELECT part_num from importedDocument);
```

I dont understand why the same `notes` and `condition_id` is set for all parts from `importedDocument`.

Comment: Your table definition for `importedDocument` has multiple primary keys (PK), which is strictly impossible. Probably foreign keys? Please provide the output of `\d importedDocument` from `psql` instead, which also includes data types and other important information. Also, also *always*, your version of Postgres.

Comment: OK but why cant I have a composite primary key?
The main idea of having composite key is that combination of 7 components of this composite primary key should be uniqe

Comment: Of course you can have a composite pk. I misunderstood your representation. If you provide the table definition like advised such misunderstandings won't occur. Either way, including condition and quantity in the primary key is a rather uncommon design. I would consider a [`serial`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL) column as surrogate primary key.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is *incomplete*. Since there can be multiple matches in table `importedDocument` for a single row in table `part` you have to define what to pick in such a case.

Your solution is *straight out wrong* in any case. Your condition is that `part.part_num` exists in *any* row of `importedDocument`, but there is no actual connection between individual rows, so you end up with an effective `CROSS JOIN` (a [Cartesian product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product)), *every* row in `part` is updated with *every* qualifying row `importedDocument` (i e. many times!), the (arbitrarily determined) last update sticks. Expensive nonsense, definitely not what you want.

Use instead:

```
UPDATE part p
SET    active       = i.active, 
       notes        = i.notes,      
       weight       = i.weight, 
       condition_id = i.condition_id
FROM  (
   SELECT DISTINCT ON (part_num)
          part_num, active, notes, weight, condition_id
   FROM   importedDocument
   ORDER  BY part_num, <column / expression to define which row to pick>
   ) i
WHERE  p.part_num = i.part_num;
```

More information for `DISTINCT ON` in this related answer:
[Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564)

If you don't provide additional `ORDER BY` items in place of `<column / expression to define which row to pick>`, the query still works, but Postgres decides arbitrarily which row to pick from multiple matches.