# Postgres UPDATE FROM set value according to result of other query

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update

I'm stuck with an `UPDATE`. My tables originally were:

```
Clients
------------------
ID
Emails
Notification_type

Contracts
------------------
ID
Client_id (FK)

Contracts_document_types
------------------
Contract_id (FK)
Document_type_id (FK)
```

And I could notify basing on `Clients` table. Then I had to change the notification method. My database changed to:

```
Contracts_document_types
------------------
Contract_id (FK)
Document_type_id (FK)
Notification_method_id (FK)

Notification_methods
------------------
ID
emails
notification_type
```

I was able to create the necessary `notification_methods` entries based on clients, but I didn't find a way to associate in `contracts_document_types.notification_method_id`. It is possible to find the `notification_method` based on `clients` table, but the table to be updated is `contracts_document_types` and I cannot figure out how.

My idea is something like:

```
update contracts_document_types
set notification_method_id = query.nm_id
from ( select NM.id as nm_id from notification_methods NM
       inner join clients C on C.emails = NM.emails 
             and C.notification_type = NM.notification_type    
) as query
where ????????
```

It's possible to get to `contracts_document_types` from `clients` (where the information lies), but I could not associate them to the right users.  I'm missing something important about the iteration process in `UPDATE FROM` statement.

Resume: 1 client has many contracts_document_types, I have an notification_method created based on clients.  I cannot find a way to put the right notification_method on each client (all contracts_document_types from that client).

Comment: Could you give some examples of clients, their contracts, and a short description how do you find a notification for this example data ?

Comment: Consider using temporary tables to make the very update statement as simple as possible. I would say that using subqueries in updates is not a good idea, because it's more difficult to understand and it's mistake-prone...

Comment: @voytech: On the upside: as soon as you *do* understand it, it magically transforms into an excellent idea.

Comment: Exactly.  Anyone may resolve it creating a script in any programming language or using temporary tables, is not a bad idea, but this statement seems pretty strong, the time spent strugling will pay off soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My educated guess, it should work like this:

```
UPDATE contracts_document_types cd
SET    notification_method_id = q.nm_id
FROM  (
   SELECT co.id AS co_id, nm.id AS nm_id
   FROM   contracts co
   JOIN   clients   cl ON cl.id = co.client_id
   JOIN   notification_methods nm USING (emails, notification_type)
   ) q
WHERE  cd.contract_id = q.co_id;
```

You just forgot to add the `contracts` table as missing link. Details for [`UPDATE` in the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-update.html).

`USING` is just a syntax shorthand. If `emails` and `notification_type` can be ambiguous, be explicit like you had it:

```
JOIN   notification_methods nm ON nm.emails = cl.emails
                              AND nm.notification_type = cl.notification_type
```

Simpler yet, you don't even need a subquery:

```
UPDATE contracts_document_types cd
SET    notification_method_id = nm.id
FROM   contracts co
JOIN   clients   cl ON cl.id = co.client_id
JOIN   notification_methods nm USING (emails, notification_type)
WHERE  cd.contract_id = co.id;
```

Related:

- [UPDATE from result of SELECT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17889458/update-from-result-of-select/17891377#17891377)
- [Update a column of a table with a column of another table in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13473499/update-a-column-of-a-table-with-a-column-of-another-table-in-postgresql/13473660#13473660)

Comment: Worked as you posted, just the cd abbreviation on update wasn't working, I took off and it ran.  Thank you sir.

Comment: @PedroIvan Great! The *table alias* `cd` should work, too ([see documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-update.html)) - unless you are on a very old version of Postgres. That feature was introduced with Postgres 8.2. It's just a syntax shortcut for convenience here and totally optional.